# Factorization of Lower Triangular Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to factorize a lower triangular Toeplitz Matrix, using binary matrices and a vector of elements?

For example, the Toeplitz matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}
\\
a&0&0&0\\
b&a&0&0\\
c&b&a&0\\
d&c&b&a
\end{array}\right]$$
using the vector 
$$\left[\begin{array} .a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right]$$
and other binary matrices (i.e. with elements of only $0,1$)?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Google search for
"lower triangular Toeplitz Matrix"
comes up with this:

ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/research/papers/TRENCH_TN_6.PDF

with the title
"Inverses of lower triangular Toeplitz matrices".

This looks helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this GNU Octave script does it

```
T = toeplitz(rand(4,1),[0,0,0,0]);
t = T(:,1); % first column
P = diag(ones(6,1),1) + diag(1,-6); P  = inv(P);
Z = 0*P;
M= [P^0,Z,Z,Z;Z,P^1,Z,Z;Z,Z,P^2,Z;Z,Z,Z,P^3];
v=M*kron(ones(4,1),[zeros(3,1);t]);
T-reshape(v,[7,4])(4:7,:)
```

The binary matrices used is generator for the matrix representation of cyclic group $C_7$ : ($\bf P$ in the code)

It's exponent placed along the diagonal and fill the rest with zeros.
Then pad the $(a,b,c,d)^T$ vector with 3 zeros (or $N-1$ zeros, where $N$ is size of vector)

Trimming can probably be applied to make this smaller and tidier.

The "reshaping" and tidying can be implemented by binary selection matrices.